# Page turnings clarification

Tags: short-story, clarity, pages

In my story, to go to next page I wrote "I completed my sentence and turned the page.". But now I want to go back to my previous page, I wrote "I realized that I have missed something, so I turned the previous page back."

Please let me know if this is correct way of writing, also please help me with other ways to write the same intentions.

Comment: @Standback Could you move this to english.SE, I'd think it would be on topic there.

Comment: @what I checked, and it's not on topic at EL&U without a specific question or a problem with what's wrong.

Comment: NotesArt, you might find http://ell.stackexchange.com/ useful - it's better geared for questions like "is this ok" and basic English phrasing/grammar . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English you "turn the page" to go to the next page in a book, and you "turn back the page" to go to the previous page.

In your situation, you might write something like:

> I completed the sentence and turned the page.
>
> I realized I had missed something and turned back the page.